# How to Create Variables Dynamically Based on List using C#?

Tags: c#, generic-list

This is my Code

```
Public List<string> Values{get;set;}
```

In the above list contains multiple values . For Example ["10","20","30"] . I want to create three variables with list values(a="10",b="20",c="30") in c#.net . If List Count is Zero No need to Create Variables.

Comment: You need to think of your design. Why do you need variable creation for each value (just curious)?

Comment: what does this have to do with MVC? And most importantly...variables doesn't say much here if there's no context? Are we talking about JS variables or adding private members to a class or local variables inside a method?

Comment: Yes me too thought the same @HariPrasad..

Comment: Well you could do some convoluted code to define say a-z and assign to a-> whatever is relevant, and then check what you used and didnt.. but why would you need to do that?

Comment: Please explain the context in more detail.

Comment: Dictionary<string,string> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ExpandoObject`:

```
  using System.Dynamic;

  ...

  List<string> Values = new List<string>() {
    "10", "20", "30"
  };

  ...

  dynamic variables = new ExpandoObject();

  for (int i = 0; i < Values.Count; ++i)
    (variables as IDictionary<String, Object>).Add(
       ((char) ('a' + i)).ToString(), 
       Values[i]);

  ...

  // 10
  Console.Write(variables.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
if (Values.Count != 0){   
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
            new Dictionary<string, string>();
    char key = 'a';
    for (i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++){
        dictionary.Add(key, Values[i]);
        key = (key == 'z'? 'a': (char)(input + 1));
    }
}
```